# How to use .vsdx file in Doxygen for Document generation

Tags: doxygen, visio, documentation-generation

is it possible to include a .vsdx Microsoft Visio file into source code as a image and use doxygen for compiling the documentation. If so, How?

Comment: When the `vsdx` file is an image format that is understood by your doxygen output format (HTML, LaTeX ...) you could use the `\image` command. Otherwise you have to translate the file to e.g. a png, svg, ... file and use this with the `image` command. Btw. which version of doxygen are you using. Can you show a small example of what you try to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Save the Visio .vsdx files as .png images or as .pdf files.